# sed or awk: remove string which starts with number and ends with rpm

Tags: awk, sed

I know a regex to remove from string all numbers

```
sed 's/-[0-9].*//'
```

I want to remove all strings which start with numbers and end with rpm
For example
with those strings

```
software.v2.strings.strings.3.30.rpm
software.64.7.7.0.strings.4.30.rpm
soft.1-4-4.string.44.rpm
```

must remove only the last numbers which end with rpm

So will return

```
software.v2.strings.strings 
software.64.7.7.0.strings 
soft.1-4-4.string
```

Someone know how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s/(\.[0-9]+)*\.rpm$//`

That is a group of (dot and numbers) arbitrary amount of times followed by ".rpm" and end of the line.

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: Can't test right now but try adding `g` after `//`?

Comment: yes i did this but doesn't work

Comment: hmm, if `$` doesn't work, as it matches end of pattern space, try replacing it with `\n`or nothing and removing `g` flag. I'll read up on multiline mode.

Comment: if `$` doesn't match, you may have Windows style line endings, try using `dos2unix`.  Many of the special regex characters need to be escaped in my `sed`: `s/\(\.[0-9]\+\)*\.rpm$//`

Answer (score 3):

How about this perl one liner?

`perl -pe 's/[\d.]+\.rpm$//'`

How does it work:

- `-p` Print results after executing perl code on each line in input file
- `-e` Perl code
- `s/[\d\.]\.rpm$//` Substitute characters containing any combination of digits, dots but ending with `.rpm` with blank string. See `perldoc perlre` for more about perl regular expressions.

Comment: works fine  nice

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you also want to get rid off all the dots around the numbers, here is my attempt:

```
sed 's/[[:digit:].]*\.rpm$//'
```